# "Chiagne e fotte" in Italiano

Tags: idioms, regional

L'efficace espressione napoletana si sente usare spesso negli ultimi tempi, probabilmente dopo la [sceneggiata di pianto in televisione](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kuIPnryWXIA) dell'ex Ministro Fornero.

**Chiagne e fotte**:

> - 'espressione vernacolare napoletana chiagni e fotti (o chiagne e fotte) ; in italiano: «piangi e fotti») è un volgarismo che costituisce una formula proverbiale della tradizione partenopea. Viene usata, di solito, per sottolineare e stigmatizzare un tipico atteggiamento umano, opportunista e ipocrita.

Esiste  un  modo di dire analogo in Italiano?

Comment: Non che io sappia. Chiaramente mi vengono in mente un buon numero di perifrasi ma nulla che abbia la stessa immediatezza ed efficacia. Domanda interessante.

Answer (score 5):

Non è la stessa cosa, ma è imparentato con le “lacrime di coccodrillo” (in cui si finge di rammaricarsi per un problema altrui di cui siamo causa).

Answer (score 4):

"Piangere il morto per fregare il vivo", prevalente in settentrione ma italiano e attestato a stampa (cercando su Google Books).

Answer (score 3):

*Chi piange frega chi ride* è la versione italiana di un altro detto napoletano (*chi chiagn fott a chi rir*).
In termini meno colloquiali potrebbe essere utilizzato "ipocrita raggiratore" o, in termini più giornalistici, "inciucio".